# Get disabled related entry's data within plugin

Tags: plugin-development, relations

I'm looping through products (`$rawProduct`) within Craft Commerce, within a plugin, and returning products which fulfill a certain criteria. I'm then returning a `$products` array of objects with the following:

```
$product = new \stdClass;
$product->url = $rawProduct->url;
$product->courseTitle = $rawProduct->relatedFieldTitle[0]['title'];
$product->courseUrl = $rawProduct->relatedFieldTitle[0]['url'];
array_push($products, $product);
```

This is working great. However, when the target entry of the related field is disabled, lines three and four above are returning empty. I'd like to get this information no matter whether the target entry is disabled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came across this same situation myself. Was able to resolve with:

`$entry->entriesFieldWithDisabledEntry->status(null)->first()`

Comment: This sounds perfect. Nice one.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Do you maybe have a Twig solution also? just opened https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/36514/craft-3-twig-search-query-for-entry-with-custom-entriesfield-containing-disabl

Answer (score 2):

To pull both enabled and disabled entries from an Entries field, you can do this:

```
$entry->entriesField->status = 'any';
$relatedEntries = $entry->entriesField->find();
```

Answer (score 1):

Related fields will always ignore disabled entries.

Instead of disabling entries, you could add a lightswitch field to your entries to indicate whether or not they are disabled. This would preserve relations to those entries and would return all entries, regardless of the value of the lightswitch field.

When fetching entries in other circumstances, if you only wanted to show enabled entries, you would need to always need to explicitly include a condition that the lightswitch was on (`=='1'`).

Comment: Thanks Steve. I'd prefer to do this without querying the DB for the disabled entry, so if you're right, then this is what I'll have to do as a workaround.

Comment: It's the easiest way to handle it. I've used a similar system on a site I've built recently and it works really well. As far as I know, it's the only way to keep relations live whilst disabling direct access to entries that are the target of those relations.