# Craft 3 - Twig search query for entry with custom EntriesField containing disabled entry

Tags: craft3, templating, search, query, status

I have a search form with 1 simple input (q)

I also have 2 sections: SECTION-A & SECTION-B

The search is for entries within **SECTION A**.

The entry I'm searching for contains a custom [entriesField](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries-fields.html#settings) from SECTION B which can contain a *posible disabled* entry because they have an expiryDate. But they still need to be searchable when typing something the disabled entry contains. I can't figure out what to do with my query.

This is what i have so far: (works perfectly with an **enabled** related entry from SECTION B)

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('SECTION-A').search(searchParam).orderBy('score').all() %}
```

what I am trying:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('SECTION-A').search(searchParam ~ ' status: any').orderBy('score').all() %}
```

But this is not working, can anybody help me out here? :)

Screenshot clarification:
[image: Example]

When searching **october** (expired entry from SECTION-B), it is NOT showing me results.

When searching **november** (entry from SECTION-B), I get the results I am expecting

---

*some technical information:*

- PHP version  7.3.22
- Database driver & version    MariaDB 10.3
- Craft edition & version  Craft Pro 3.5.14

Answer (score 2):

The search parameter only searches the element that is the subject of your element query (i.e., the source entry) - it does not search related entries. For that you need to use the `relatedTo` parameter. (I'm not sure why you're getting a successful result for the November entry - perhaps the source entry also has the word November in it somewhere?).

Additionally, you'll need to use the [anyStatus](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#anystatus) parameter to fetch expired entries.

So to pull this off, you'll need to conduct the search against the other section and then find related entries, i.e.:

```
{% set sectionBEntryIds = craft.entries.section('SECTION-B').search(searchParam).anyStatus().orderBy('score').ids() %}

{% set sectionAEntries = craft.entries.section('SECTION-A').relatedTo(sectionBEntryIds).all() %}
```

Comment: Not realy, it's not the entries in the section that are disabled (because than anyStatus would be applied) It's the entry within the customField (entries field) that contains a 'expired' entry. Added a screenshot for more clarification

Comment: Pretty sure that anyStatus() takes into account expired entries? https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#status .. or are you saying that you have a custom field for the expiry date instead of the built-in one?

Comment: I've added more clarification in my question above. The Entry "test" has a custom "entriesField" where I added the entry "28-October-2020" (expired with build in expiryDate). Now, when I search for the word October, it is not giving me the "Test" entry. When searching for November, I do get back the other "Test" entry

Comment: Ah right I see now. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: That doesn't work :( I updated my question again. FYI: the entry which contains november doesn't have any tekst containing the word november. I made a new test with an extra entry in which I related a date from december, and if I search for it it comes back in the results. So there has to be some way to give a parameter into the search to ignore status from related fields right?